# EXC_BAD_ACCESS Exception while copy item to path iOS

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to copy an item from orginal path for destination path, but it throw exception while copying file. Any body can examine why? Thank in advance.

```
- (void) copyFile:(NSString*) fromPath toPath:(NSString*) toPath
{
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    BOOL success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:toPath];
    if (success)
        [fileManager removeItemAtPath:toPath error:&error];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:fromPath toPath:toPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSLog(@"fail to copy signature temp file!");
    }
}
```

I receive no error logs!

Comment: /Users/cscv/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/5414A8E2-8902-4156-A0D3-F39426BA435E/Documents/signature.pdf. I've checked it carefully before

Comment: /Users/cscv/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0/Applications/5414A8E2-8902-4156-A0D3-F39426BA435E/Documents/sign_signature.pdf

Comment: `removeItemAtPath` also returns a BOOL value, and if not success, you can log error.

Comment: in case it return NO, it throws exception. Just skip removeItemAtPath, it throws exception at copyItemAtPath!

Comment: What is the exception log? How did you get fromPath and toPath?

Comment: Did you read my post carefully? I wrote that "I receive no error logs". About fromPath and toPath, I copy it by debugging app.

Comment: Because you didn't even bother to log the error message, in your if(!success), `NSLog(@"Failed error is %@", error.localizedDescription)`, or `NSLog(@"Failed error is %@", error)`.

Comment: I try to log it before by try catch, but EXEC_BAD doesn't return any error log? Even try catch can't, how can?

Comment: Show more code or add a all exception breakpoint in project.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this error several times in relation to delegates.

Have you set the file manager's delegate? If you have be sure that the delegate is still valid when that method is executed. Add a log statement to be sure.

If you haven't set one it might be worth setting one just to see if that has an effect.